# What are the connected covers of $S^2 \times S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to understand the relation between covering maps and the fundamental group of a space. In this specific example I want to find the connected covers of $S^2 \times S^2$ but in general I'd like to know how to approach such a problem. I understand that a covering map induces a monomorphism of the fundamental groups, but I'm not sure if there needs to exist a covering space for every subgroup? Is that true? And if not necessarily, how would one even approach a problem of finding all covers?

Comment: This is pretty well explained in one of the last chapters of Munkres' book on topology.

Comment: First question to ask yourself: Knowing that a covering map induces a monomorphism of fundamental groups, what are the possibilities for the image in $\pi_1(S^2 \times S^2)$ of the induced fundamental group monomorphism?

Comment: @LeeMosher Well the group considered is $Z \times Z$ so anything of the form $Z_n \times Z_m$ ?

Comment: Hmmm.... how do you get $Z \times Z$, given that $S^2$ is simply connected?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thanks for the tip, didn't know about that book. Indeed there is a condition there for the existence of a corresponding covering map, theorem 82.1 for anyone interested.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry, I was thinking about $S^1 \times S^1$ all this time. You're right of course, the fundamental group of this is trivial so there could only be one cover?

Comment: That's it. Plus more letters to get beyond the minimum.